# Exception in iReport 5.6.0 not working

Tags: exception

im installed ireport 5.6.0 and netbeans 8.0.2, then i opened and launch an exception below the log

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Thursday, July 2, 2015 12:17:51 AM CEST
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.6.0 
  Operating System        = Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_75; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.75-b04; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_75-b13
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre
  System Locale; Encoding = es_ES (ireport); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\XD
  Current Directory       = C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0
  User Directory          = C:\Users\XD\.ireport\5.6.0
  Installation            = C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport
                            C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ide10
                            C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5
                            C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\classes;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\antlr-2.7.5.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\asm-attrs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\asm.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\barbecue-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\bsh-1.3.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\cglib-2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\cincom-jr-xmla.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-beanutils-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-collections-2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-digester-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-javaflow-20060411.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-logging-1.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-logging-api-1.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\commons-pool-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\dom4j-1.6.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\ehcache-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\eigenbase-properties.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\eigenbase-resgen.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\eigenbase-xom.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\flexdock-0.4.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\groovy-all-1.0-beta-10.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\hibernate3.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\hsqldb-1.7.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\ireport.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\itext-1.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jakarta-bcel-20050813.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\JasperBabylon-1.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jasperreports-1.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\javacup.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jcmdline-1.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jcommon-1.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jfreechart-1.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jpa.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jr-bsh-compiler.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jsmoothgen-ant-0.9.7.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jta.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jxl-2.6.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\log4j-1.2.8.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\looks-2.0-rc.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\microba-0.4.1-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\mondrian-2.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-3.1.11-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\nsisant-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\png-encoder-1.5.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\poi-2.0-final-20040126.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\rex-20070125.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\saaj-api-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\servlet.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\spring-2.0-m2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\spring-context-2.0-m2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\spring-hibernate3-2.0-m2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sqleonardo-2007.03.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\tinylaf.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\toniclf.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\xercesImpl.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\xml-apis.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
  Application Classpath   = C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\core.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_de.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_es.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_fr.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_it.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_pl.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_sq.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\core_zh_TW.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_de.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_es.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_fr.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_it.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_pl.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_sq.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_zh_TW.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\core\locale\core_ireport.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_de.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_es.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_it.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\core_nb_zh_TW.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_de.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_es.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_it.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_TW.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVERTENCIA [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module com.jaspersoft.ireport: added = [module org.netbeans.modules.options.api/1 > 1.4, module org.netbeans.modules.db/1 > 1.24] removed = [module org.netbeans.modules.db/0-1 > 1.21.0.5, module org.netbeans.modules.options.api/0-1 > 1.5.1]; details: [Major release version of module changed from 0 to 1 to signal stability; update your dependencies]
ADVERTENCIA [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: The extension C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\ext\slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar may be multiply loaded by modules: [C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\com-jaspersoft-ireport-hadoop-hive.jar, C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\com-jaspersoft-ireport.jar]; see: http://www.netbeans.org/download/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/classpath.html#class-path
ADVERTENCIA [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: The extension C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\ext\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar may be multiply loaded by modules: [C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\com-jaspersoft-ireport-hadoop-hive.jar, C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\com-jaspersoft-ireport.jar]; see: http://www.netbeans.org/download/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/classpath.html#class-path
ADVERTENCIA [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the module org.netbeans.modules.db uses org.openide.options which is deprecated: Usar preferentemente org.openide.util.NbPreferences.
ADVERTENCIA [o
    org.netbeans.modules.print [6.5.1 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver [1.0 140528]
    org.netbeans.modules.dbapi [1.7.1.30 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.metadata.model/0 [0.1.1 200903060201]
    org.openide.execution [1.12.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.utilities/1 [1.29.1 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.standalone [1.0 140528]
    org.netbeans.libs.jna/1 [1.1.2 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.settings/1 [1.15.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.core.windows/2 [2.12.3.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.core.nativeaccess/1 [1.1.2 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui [1.2.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.plain.lib/1 [1.6.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.properties.syntax/1 [1.20.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.web.flyingsaucer/1 [1.2.1 1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.core.execution/1 [1.12.1.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.core.output2/1 [1.10.1.1 1 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.components [1.0 140528]
    org.netbeans.modules.defaults/1 [1.5.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview [1.0.3 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.core [1.7.3 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.editor [1.7.1.30 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.plain/2 [1.7.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.core.ide/1 [1.12.1 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.mongodb [0.9.3 140528]
    org.netbeans.modules.extbrowser/1 [1.13.1 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.jrx [1.0 140528]
    org.netbeans.modules.projectui [1.15.3.1.6 1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.api [1.4.1 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples [1.0 140528]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.mysql [0.1.3 2 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.db.drivers [1.2.1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.languages.refactoring/0 [1.0.1.1 1 200903060201]
    org.netbeans.modules.core.kit [1.2.4 200903060201]
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.addons [1.0 140528]
java.net.UnknownHostException: ireport.sf.net
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.heartbeat.Installer.run(Installer.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.core.windows.persistence]: [PersistenceManager.getTopComponentForID] Problem when deserializing TopComponent for tcID:'WelcomeTopComponent'. Reason: Error reading MultiFileObject@ed38d[Windows2Local/Components/WelcomeTopComponent.settings]: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE settings PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Session settings 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/sessionsettings-1_0.dtd">
<settings version="1.0">
    <module name="com.jaspersoft.ireport" spec="1.0"/>
    <instanceof class="org.openide.windows.TopComponent"/>
    <instanceof class="com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent"/>
    <instance class="com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent" method="getDefault"/>
</settings>

Method: getDefault
Class: class com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent
Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE settings PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Session settings 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/sessionsettings-1_0.dtd">
<settings version="1.0">
    <module name="com.jaspersoft.ireport" spec="1.0"/>
    <instanceof class="org.openide.windows.TopComponent"/>
    <instanceof class="com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent"/>
    <instance class="com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent" method="getDefault"/>
</settings>

Method: getDefault
Class: class com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent
Caused: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.GraySeparator.<init>(GraySeparator.java:46)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent.initComponents(WelcomeTopComponent.java:90)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent.<init>(WelcomeTopComponent.java:49)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent.getDefault(WelcomeTopComponent.java:341)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.netbeans.modules.settings.convertors.XMLSettingsSupport$SettingsRecognizer.createFromMethod(XMLSettingsSupport.java:670)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Error reading MultiFileObject@ed38d[Windows2Local/Components/WelcomeTopComponent.settings]
    at org.netbeans.modules.settings.convertors.XMLSettingsSupport$SettingsRecognizer.createFromMethod(XMLSettingsSupport.java:678)
    at org.netbeans.modules.settings.convertors.XMLSettingsSupport$SettingsRecognizer.instanceCreate(XMLSettingsSupport.java:581)
    at org.netbeans.modules.settings.convertors.SerialDataConvertor$SettingsInstance.instanceCreate(SerialDataConvertor.java:420)
[catch] at org.netbeans.core.windows.persistence.PersistenceManager.getTopComponentPersistentForID(PersistenceManager.java:531)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.persistence.PersistenceManager.getTopComponentForID(PersistenceManager.java:641)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.getTopComponentForID(PersistenceHandler.java:422)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.initModeFromConfig(PersistenceHandler.java:386)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.load(PersistenceHandler.java:205)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.load(WindowSystemImpl.java:69)
    at org.netbeans.core.NonGui$2.run(NonGui.java:178)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:738)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:708)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE settings PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Session settings 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/sessionsettings-1_0.dtd">
<settings version="1.0">
    <module name="com.jaspersoft.ireport" spec="1.0"/>
    <instanceof class="org.openide.windows.TopComponent"/>
    <instanceof class="com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent"/>
    <instance class="com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent" method="getDefault"/>
</settings>
TODO [null]: Method: getDefault
TODO [null]: Class: class com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.WelcomeTopComponent
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx512m
    -Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999
    -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\platform9
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\ide10;C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-5.6.0\nb6.5
    -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Users\XD\.ireport\5.6.0
    -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy=DIRECT
    -Dnetbeans.system_http_non_proxy_hosts=
    -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
Compiler: HotSpot Client Compiler
Heap memory usage: initial 256,0MB maximum 494,9MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 12,2MB maximum 544,0MB
Garbage collector: Copy (Collections=2 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: MarkSweepCompact (Collections=1 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=5125 total loaded=5125 unloaded 0
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 2.147.483.647
INFORMACIÓN [null]: Memoría total física 2.147.483.647
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 1000 for both Menu/Tools/com-jaspersoft-ireport-designer-standalone-actions-ImportSettingsAction.shadow and Menu/Tools/org-netbeans-modules-favorites-templates-TemplatesAction.instance
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Menu/Window/ marked with the position attribute: [LayersAction.shadow], but some are: [FormattingToolsAction.shadow, OutlineAction.shadow, ErrorHandlerAction.shadow, IRConsoleAction.shadow, GenericInspectorAction.shadow, RepositoryAction.shadow, JRViewerAction.shadow, ViewFavoritesTabAction.shadow, StylesLibraryAction.shadow, ViewRuntimeTabAction.shadow, ShowPaletteAction.shadow, org-netbeans-core-actions-GlobalPropertiesAction.shadow, WelcomeAction.shadow, Output, SwitchToRecentDocumentAction.shadow, ProgressListAction.shadow, Separator3.instance, CloseWindowAction.shadow, MaximizeWindowAction.shadow, org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-UndockAction.shadow, Separator4.instance, CloneDocumentAction.shadow, CloseAllDocumentsAction.shadow, CloseAllButThisAction.shadow, DocumentsAction.shadow, Separator5.instance, org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-ResetWindowsAction.shadow]
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
ADVERTENCIA [org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject]: instanceClass was a com.jaspersoft.ireport.samples.OpenSampleAction
Action Basic_report created!
Action Elements created!
Action Parameters_and_Variables created!
Action Groups created!
Action Fonts created!
Action Charts created!
Action Subreports created!
Action Crosstabs created!
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache]: Processing URL: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5.1/uc/final/beta/catalog.xml.gz?unique=099971725-1fa0-4a5d-a767-76a5147f8c69_bb9c14e4-9363-47a6-8411-02a1c2bfe69e
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache]: Processing URL: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5.1/uc/final/stable/catalog.xml.gz?unique=099971725-1fa0-4a5d-a767-76a5147f8c69_bb9c14e4-9363-47a6-8411-02a1c2bfe69e
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache]: Processing URL: http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/6.5/catalog.xml.gz
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache]: Processing URL: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5.1/uc/final/thirdparty/catalog.xml.gz?unique=099971725-1fa0-4a5d-a767-76a5147f8c69_bb9c14e4-9363-47a6-8411-02a1c2bfe69e
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache]: Reading URL http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5.1/uc/final/beta/catalog.xml.gz?unique=099971725-1fa0-4a5d-a767-76a5147f8c69_bb9c14e4-9363-47a6-8411-02a1c2bfe69e failed (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org)
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler]: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org
java.io.IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache.notifyException(AutoupdateCatalogCache.java:188)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache.copy(AutoupdateCatalogCache.java:183)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache.writeCatalogToCache(AutoupdateCatalogCache.java:104)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogProvider.refresh(AutoupdateCatalogProvider.java:117)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services.UpdateUnitProviderImpl.refresh(UpdateUnitProviderImpl.java:153)
    at org.netbeans.api.autoupdate.UpdateUnitProvider.refresh(UpdateUnitProvider.java:158)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler$4.run(AutoupdateCheckScheduler.java:150)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.doEvaluate(RequestProcessor.java:1042)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.waitFinished(RequestProcessor.java:734)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler.refreshUpdateCenters(AutoupdateCheckScheduler.java:319)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler.scheduleRefreshProviders(AutoupdateCheckScheduler.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler.access$500(AutoupdateCheckScheduler.java:97)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler$6.run(AutoupdateCheckScheduler.java:408)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache]: Reading URL http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5.1/uc/final/stable/catalog.xml.gz?unique=099971725-1fa0-4a5d-a767-76a5147f8c69_bb9c14e4-9363-47a6-8411-02a1c2bfe69e failed (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org)
INFORMACIÓN [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui.actions.AutoupdateCheckScheduler]: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org
java.io.IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache.notifyException(AutoupdateCatalogCache.java:188)
    at org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogCache.copy(AutoupdateCatalogCache.java:183)
```

---

How can resolve this problem?

PD: iReport its open but, the iReport opens anyway but I'm afraid it does not work well, and also before opening always displays the message that there is an exception and so.

Thank all guys. . .